# continuously read json from childprocess stdout

Tags: json, node.js, stream, ipc

I want to read and send `json` messages in nodejs from and to a java childprocess. The childprocess will live for some time. Messages sent and recieved via `stdio` represent events from and to the two processes. As a result the messages have to be processed as soon as they are completed.

The Output will be in the form

```
{"type":"eventType","data":...}
{"type":"anotherEventType","data":...}
...
{"type":"anotherEventType","data":...}
```

Writing the messages is no problem but reading is. Especially since I can not rely on the messages splitting on `\n` nor that one chunk contains exactly one message.

Unfortunately every example I could find buffers the output of `stdout` until the process terminates and only than parses it. And all IPC node modules I could find use sockets which I would like to avoid.

Are there existing libraries that provide such functionality or do I have to role my own?

Comment: Are both processes implemented in Node? If so it is *very* easy to send JSON messages across through Node's IPC channel (I can elaborate in an answer if that is indeed your case).

Comment: Nope, node will spawn a java vm. edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) does exactly what I want.

```
child.stdout
    .pipe(require('JSONStream').parse())
    .on('data', processMessage);
```